# Javascript - Write content to frame in another html document

Tags: javascript, html, css, frame, frameset

Forgive me if this is a simple question, but currently I have the Javascript code:

```
function sendCode() {
   var previewFrame = parent.frames[3];
   var htmlCode = parent.frames[1].document.getElementById("inputhtml").value;
   var cssCode = parent.frames[2].document.getElementById("inputcss").value;

   previewFrame.document.write("<html><head><title></title>");
   previewFrame.document.write("<style type='text/css'>" + cssCode + "</style>");
   previewFrame.document.write("</head><body>" + htmlCode + "</body></html>");
   previewFrame.document.close();
}

function showPreview() {
   parent.document.getElementById("demo").rows="100,1,*";
}
```

However, when I add html or css to the input tag on the page and submit, nothing happens. Am I referencing this correctly? Here are the html documents in question. Thank you!

**demo.htm:**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>HTML Demo</title>
   <link href="code.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<frameset rows="100,210,*" id="demo" name="demo"> 
   <frame name="title" id="title" src="title.htm" scrolling="no" />
   <frameset cols="*,*">
      <frame name="htmlcode" id="htmlcode" src="html.htm" />
      <frame name="csscode" id="csscode" src="css.htm" />
   </frameset>
   <frame name="preview" id="output" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

**html.htm**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>HTML Code for the Demo Page</title>
   <link href="code.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <form name="code" id="code" action="">
   <p>
      &lt;body&gt;
      <textarea id="inputhtml" name="inputhtml"></textarea>
      &lt;/body&gt;
   </p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**title.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Web Design Demo Control Buttons</title>
    <link href="title.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="control" id="control" action="">
        <h2 id="demotitle">Creating Web Pages </h2>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Submit Code" id="submitCode" />
            <input type="button" value="Show Only Code" id="showCode" />
            <input type="button" value="Show Only Preview" id="showPreview" />
            <input type="button" value="Show Code and Preview" id="showBoth" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it works in internet explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge but not in Google Chrome. The code seems to be correct, but what could be causing this? Perhaps I need to reference it differently?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
var iframedoc = document.getElementById('iframeElementId').contentDocument || document.getElementById('iframeElementId').contentWindow.document;
```

**Then to edit the code in the iframe you would put:**

```
iframedoc.body.innerHTML += "<p>Hellow World</p>";
```

**Or**

```
iframedoc.head.innerHTML += "<script>alert('Hello World')</script>";
```

---

`iframedoc` is just a `document` object so it could be used like this:

- `iframedoc.addEventListener` (like document.addEventListener)
- `document.body` and `document.head`
- Etc.